# Use of Interface for data hiding

Tags: oop, encapsulation

I have an interface I with two methods func A and func B and a class C with the implementation of the interface, I have two users U1 and U2. 
I want the functionality so that if u1 accesses class C, func A should be called and if u2 accesses class C func B should be called.
How do i implement this using OOPs ?

Comment: And you want this functionality, why exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will focus on what you've *asked*. Why you would *want* to do this and whether it's actually a good idea with respect to OO design principles is another question.

First, your requirement would look similar to the following: **<sup>(note)</sup>**

```
interface I
{
    void A();
    void B();
}

// class C : I { ... }
```

Now, let's create a `User` role and two implementations for user 1 and user 2:

```
public interface User
{
    void Access(I x);
}

class User1 : User
{
    public void Access(I x)  {  x.A();  }
}

class User2 : User
{
    public void Access(I x)  {  x.B();  }
}
```

Finally, instantiate your users 1 and 2 as follows:

```
User u1 = new User1();
User u2 = new User2();
```

And "access" your C as follows:

```
I c = new C();
u1.Access(c);    // will call c.A()
u2.Access(c);    // will call c.B()
```

Note that this code almost completely leaves class `C` out of the game and instead focuses on the interface (`I`). If, however, you want your code to work specifically with `C`, simply replace `I` with `C` in the appropriate place (namely, with the parameter of method `Access`).

---

**<sup>(note:)</sup>** I've chosen C# for the examples, but translating to the language of your choice should be easy.

Answer (score 1):

### I think that what you really want is:

1. an inteface I with just 1 method
2. 2 classes implementing it in different way: func A and func B
3. Factory for that interface that take the user as parameter

### Example

Let's say:

1. U1 is Barney, U2 is Fred.
2. func A is printing "I love you Betty"
3. func B is printing "Where's my club Wilma?!"
4. interface Quote is defined with a method emitQuote()
5. classes C and D will implement I with A and B respectively
6. define a factory (factory class or factory method doesn't matter) and put the User switch there.

In this way you can call:

```
Quote q = myFactory.getQuoteFor(u);
q.emitQuote();
```

This is pure OOP and I think it's pretty simple to write in a TDD fashion.

Answer (score 0):

More clarification is definitely needed to determine exactly what you're trying to do, but...

Rather than having the logic in the User class, thinking OO-like, maybe a factory, like:

```
abstract class C : I
{
  public void A() { }
  public void B() { }
  public abstract void CallMethod();
}

class C1 : C
{
  public override void CallMethod() { A(); }
}

class C2 : C
{
  public override void CallMethod() { B(); }
}

static class Factory
{
  public static I GetI(User user) 
  {
    // This is where your if blocks will go, 
    // and it will return either a new C1 or a new C2
  }
}
```

This has the benefit of allowing the user to remain simple with no business code in it. The factory has to only be smart enough to know which C it wants to create based on the user. All of the actual work of calling the real method is done in the C itself.

**EDIT**: You may have to fiddle with the interface and the C class a little - in this case, you'd need the CallMethod() method to be in the interface. Or your factory could return a C instead of an I. Of course, without knowing the whole story, it's hard to say which is correct.